# Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ given the disjoint open sets $U,V$ s.t. $A \subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Show that $A$ and $B$ are separated.

I have to show that $A,B$ separated $\rightarrow$ $\overline{A} \cap B$ and $\overline{B} \cap A$ are both empty.

I have that $\mathbb{R} - V $ is a closed set which contains $A$, and $A \subseteq U$, so $A \subset \mathbb{R} - V$. But $A \cap B \subset \mathbb{R} - V$.  $\mathbb{R}- V \cap B = \emptyset$ so it follows that $A \cap B = \emptyset$

I feel like this could use some polish or I am missing something. Anyone suggestions or alternatives would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Are we to assume that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets containing $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @AlexS, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No generality is lost by letting $A=U$ and $B=V$. Consider $v$ such that $v\in V$ and $v\in\overline{U}$. Then there is a sequence $(u_{n})_{n}$ satisfying $u_{n}\in U$ (and hence $u_{n}\notin V$) and $u_{n}\rightarrow v$. But since $V$ is open, we can find a neighbourhood of $v$ which, for some $N$, contains all $u_{n}$ with $n\geq N$. This is a contradiction, since $U$ and $V$ were assumed disjoint.

Note that nothing beyond the fact that $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is a metric space was needed.

Comment: Do we naturally assume "set" in this case means "interval", or can it apply to other kinds of sets, like the Cantor set? By the way I don't know what a metric space is yet, we haven't made it that far into Topology yet, but probably we will pretty soon.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ above are arbitrary open subsets of the space; they need not be intervals (also, recall that the Cantor set is closed). Topology before metric spaces is an interesting choice of curriculum. Feels strange to me.

Comment: Right, the Cantor set is closed. Thanks, I think I'm sort of grasping the idea, anyway. I am learning from "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott. This is the way the material is presented. Not sure when we get into metric spaces, maybe in Abstract Algebra or Analysis II.